# Apache Flume stuck after exec flume-ng

Tags: apache, hadoop, flume, flume-ng

I need help.

I've downloaded Apache Flume and installed outside Hadoop, just wanna try netcat logging through console.
I used 1.6.0 version.

Here's my conf https://gist.github.com/ans-4175/297e2b4fc0a67d826b4b

Here's how I started it

```
bin/flume-ng agent -c conf -f conf/netcat.conf Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -n Agent1
```

But it's stuck after only printed these output

```
Info: Sourcing environment configuration script /root/apache-flume/conf/flume-env.sh
Info: Including Hive libraries found via () for Hive access
+ exec /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Xms100m -Xmx2000m -cp '/root/apache-flume/conf:/root/apache-flume/lib/*:/root/apache-flume/lib/*:/lib/*' -Djava.library.path= org.apache.flume.node.Application -f conf/netcat.conf Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -n Agent1
```

Any suggestions for simple start and install?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

dumb me, it should be

```
bin/flume-ng agent -c conf -f conf/netcat.conf -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG,console -n Agent1
```